# How to Edit CSS pseudo element using React Props

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-props, pseudo-element

I want to pass the colour inside products.js to Cards.jsx  tag just like other using the propes , so that every card should have the colour provided in products.js file.

Cards.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Style from "style-it";

function Card({ name, price, colour, img_ref }) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="card">
        <Style>
          {`
        .container .card:before {
          background: ${colour};
          
        }
      `}
        </Style>
        <div className="imgBx">
          <img src={img_ref} alt="Shoe_pic"></img>
        </div>
        <div className="contentBx">
          <h2>{name}</h2>
          <div className="size">
            <h3>Size :</h3>
            <span>7</span>
            <span>8</span>
            <span>9</span>
            <span>10</span>
          </div>
          <div className="color">
            <h3>Price: &#8377; {price}.00</h3>
          </div>
          <a href="www">Buy Now</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import products from "../products";
import Card from "./Card";

function createcard(products) {
  return (
    <Card
      key={products.id}
      name={products.name}
      price={products.price}
      colour={products.colour}
      img_ref={products.img_ref}
    />
  );
}
function App() {
  return <div>{products.map(createcard)}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

products.js

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Nike Air Max 97",
    price: "16,995",
    colour: "#B7B7B7",
    Available_colour: "",
    img_ref: "https://i.ibb.co/Ct2vRDB/image-l-Rng-U5d-YP-transformed.png"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Air Jordan 1 Mid",
    price: "11,495",
    colour: "#1A79BE",
    Available_colour: "",
    img_ref: "https://i.postimg.cc/MpznY49p/image-OYyx-C3jz-X-transformed.png "
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Jordan Nu Retro 1 Low",
    price: "9,195",
    colour: "#6C584C",
    Available_colour: "",
    img_ref: "https://i.postimg.cc/N2jyV5Tm/image-hw-Kf2fnra-transformed.png"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Nike Kiger 9",
    price: "12,795",
    colour: "#EE4C21",
    Available_colour: "",
    img_ref: "https://i.postimg.cc/kXGSrLxY/image-Swva-GAh-Ag-transformed.png"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Jordan Stadium 90",
    price: "12,795",
    colour: "#703F2A",
    Available_colour: "",
    img_ref: "https://i.postimg.cc/c4fmCr9t/image-ka-YFUs-WS4-transformed.png"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Nike Dunk Low SE",
    price: "9,695",
    colour: "#D8B98F",
    Available_colour: "",
    img_ref: "https://i.postimg.cc/Qt5BmWWp/image-Q0-Tx20-Z9v-transformed.png"
  }
];

export default products;
```

I tried using  Tag to change the colour in Cards.jsx but the colour of the last item in products.js gets applied to all the Cards item

Comment: IMO, if you create css classes which would set the pseudo element how you need it, and then pass that class name down and set it onto the card, this might work for you. I've not used `style-it` though (look into using style directly with React too).

Comment: Also looks like `style-it` wants you to wrap all the JSX inside the `<Style>` tags: https://jsfiddle.net/8mjcqv6e/1/